# How to create phonegap database

Tags: android, ios, html, sqlite, cordova

I found this phonegap sqlLite tutorial

https://phonegappro.com/tutorials/phonegap-sqlite-tutorial-with-example-apache-cordova/

So I followed these instructions but from the very begining didn't understand where to write the Step 1: Create a new PhoneGap / Apache Cordova Project

"cordova create SQLiteExample com.phonegappro.sqlite SQLiteExample"

is it in the config.xml ?

I am using the online Phonegap builder.

Comment: A link has been moved to https://codesundar.com/cordova-sqlite-storage/

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial is intended for building the app from the beginning. Taken you have config.xml file already, you should be ok to skip to step 3.

Follow the official documentation at http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/plugins/ and combine that with the SQLite plugin you wish to install (but I suggest using this one - https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage)